# Checking corectness of parsers in Haskell

Tags: parsing, debugging, haskell, haskell-prelude

For a uni assignment I need to write parsers in Haskell, right now I have the following parser i think is correct:

```
parseYear :: Parser Char Year
parseYear = Year <$> ...
```

I want to check if it works, for example with `> parseYear "2004"` in ghci. this command is not valid, but i there another way to quickly check if a parser I'm writing is correct?

Edit:
Example, for the parser:`nesting :: Parser Char Int`, this would be what i want
[image]

Comment: Which parsing library?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin uu-tc

Comment: Depending on what `Parser` is, you need some function (`runParser`?) to *extract* a function that can be called on a string. `runParser nesting "()(())()"`. (And don't post images; that picture could easily be entered as regular text.)

Comment: What makes you think that `parseYear "2004"` is not valid?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin this gives an error: "The function parseYear is applied to one value argument, but its type Parser Char Year' has none"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment responses, I understand that you're using the `uu-tc` library, but your `Parser` type does not come from `ParseLib.Simple`, because it's not a function.

This means your `Parser` type must come either from `ParseLib.Parallel` or from `ParseLib.Abstract`. Both of those modules define their `Parser` type as `data`, and both expose a `parse` function - [here's](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-tc-2015.1.1/docs/ParseLib-Abstract-Core.html#v:parse) the one from `ParseLib.Abstract` and [here's](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-tc-2015.1.1/docs/ParseLib-Parallel-Core.html#v:parse) the one from `ParseLib.Parallel`.

Both these `parse` functions have the same shape: they take a `Parser` as first parameter and an input list as second. So that's how you would call it:

```
import ParseLib.(either Parallel or Abstract).Core (parse)

> parse parseYear "2004"
```